# Familial exemption for investment advisor

Tags: united-states, licensing, finance, sec

My parents have asked me to trade for them and they offered  me  a fraction of any profit. My plan is to set up a limited trade agreement and then manage the account's trades.

Before doing so, I want  make sure that I will not be in violation of any regulations. Based on my research, I would not need a series 7 license. Because this is for immediate family, would I also be exempt from registering as an IAR?

Comment: This is more of a legal question than one of personal finance.  You might want to consider getting a limited power-of-attorney from your parents to operate your parents' accounts, again more a matter for law.SE than money.SE.

Comment: @dilipsarwate Thank you, I have moved it over to law.SE.